# Selenium: How to keep scrolling the page and stop scrolling when the target url is met?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, nlp

I want the page to scroll down automatically until a specific url is met. Here is how I code:

```
urls = []
target_url = https://example.com
pause_time = 0.5
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
     links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@data-urn, "urn:li:activity:")]')
     for link in links:
          if link.get_attribute('href') != target_url:
               urls.append(link.get_attribute('href')
          elif link.get_attribute('href') == target_url:
               break
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
     time.sleep(pause_time)
     new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
     if new_height == last_height:
          break
     last_height = new_height
```

First question is how do I scroll down the page by pixel? I want it to scroll by 1000 pixel instead of straight scrolling down to the bottom of the page.

Second question is the code keeps scrolling even the target url is met, do anyone have any idea how to stop the scrolling once the target url is met?

Answer (score 1):

To scroll x amount every time, you should use `scrollBy`. The reason it doesn't leave when it finds the link is it only breaks out of the for loop. You need to set it up to break out of the while loop as well. I've added some changes to your code that will allow it to break out of the loop when the link has been found

```
urls = []
target_url = https://example.com
pause_time = 0.5
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
link_found = false
while not link_found:
     links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@data- urn,"urn:li:activity:")]')
     for link in links:
          if link.get_attribute('href') != target_url:
               urls.append(link.get_attribute('href')
          elif link.get_attribute('href') == target_url:
               link_found = true
               break
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000);")
     time.sleep(pause_time)
     new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
     if new_height == last_height:
          break
     last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the scroll of selenium [scroll-to-element](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/#scroll-to-element), it maybe more suitable
the definition of is 
`scroll_from_origin(self, scroll_origin: ScrollOrigin, delta_x: int, delta_y: int):`

**perform()** can move down one by one, once it find the href, it will break the while loop. so you can use a little step one by one.

**from_viewport()** used to locate the first coordinate in the screen.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.wheel_input import ScrollOrigin

urls = []
target_url = https://example.com
pause_time = 0.6
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
     links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@data-urn, "urn:li:activity:")]')
     for link in links:
          if link.get_attribute('href') != target_url:
               urls.append(link.get_attribute('href')
          elif link.get_attribute('href') == target_url:
               break
     scroll_origin = ScrollOrigin.from_viewport(10, 10)
     ActionChains(driver)\
        .scroll_from_origin(scroll_origin, 0, 100)\
        .perform()
     time.sleep(pause_time)
     new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
     if new_height == last_height:
          break
     last_height = new_height
```